# Validation handling in redux

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, redux

Considering a reducer like this ( I'm using [redux-action](https://redux-actions.js.org) library )

```
export const reducer = handleActions({
  [REMOVE_CATEGORY]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    // Do other stuff...
  }),
  [TOGGLE_CATEGORY]: (state, action) => {
    const category = action.payload.category
    const selectedCategory = _.findWhere(state.categories, {name: category.name})
    const activeCategories = _.filter(state.categories, {active: true})

    if (activeCategories.length < 4 && selectedCategory.active === true) {
      return {
        ...state,
        didToggleFail: true
      }
    }

    return {
      didToggleFail: false,
      isRequesting: false,
      categories: state.categories.map(
        category => category.name === action.payload.category.name ? {...category, active: !category.active} : category
      )
    }
  },
  [OTHER_ACTION]: (state,action) => ({
    ...state, 
    // Do other stuff..
  })
})
```

I find myself facing a simple problem which maybe comes from my bad approach to the solution;

Every `action` in my reducer basically spread the pre-existing state but there's a field, `didToggleFail` that is set based on various condition.

Now my problem is: `didToggleFail` which I'm using for a synchronous validation, is going to be in my state forever until unset.

I'm using `didToggleFail` inside a `componentDidUpdate` like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
if(this.props.reducer.didToggleFail)
   showError() 
}
...
```

As you can see my problem is that if I dispatch other actions and the field is still set to `true` it will always trigger the error.

How should handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing after the error is displayed, user will be provided an option to close it ( or autoclose after a timeout ). At that point, dispatch another `UNSET_TOGGLE_FAIL` to set back `didToggleFail` to false. This should prevent multiple triggers.

But, the optimal solution depends on what `showError()` does. Is it a render method or another redux action dispatch. If it is a pure render, I would suggest moving inside the component's `render` as `componentDidUpdate` will get invoked after every re-render and if you do not unset `didToggleFail`, it might lead to a loop.